# How to use SpringSercurity in SpringCloud

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have implemented three microservices. sysadmin is for user management and provides some user identity permission queries. Authentication-server is an authentication service, which implements the normal functions of spring security. But my authentication-server needs to get data from sysadmin. Here I use feign-api. Here I implement a simple client service to get data from sysadmin.

[This is the github address of my project](https://github.com/bluehhjs/spring-cloud-security-demo/tree/main/spring-cloud-security-demo)

Let me get straight to the point and look at the error reports of my project.

[error reported 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOrM7.png)

[error reported 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg4nA.jpg)

[error reported 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgL3N.jpg)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:222) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1127) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.destroy(NamedContextFactory.java:113) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1183) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.wen.authentication.server.AuthenticationServerApplication.main(AuthenticationServerApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]

2024-03-17T23:39:36.537+08:00  INFO 12524 --- [feign-api] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-17T23:39:36.546+08:00  INFO 12524 --- [feign-api] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-17T23:39:36.561+08:00 ERROR 12524 --- [feign-api] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sysAdminClient': Error creating bean with name 'com.wen.feign.sysadmin.clients.SysAdminClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.wen.authentication.server.AuthenticationServerApplication.main(AuthenticationServerApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.wen.feign.sysadmin.clients.SysAdminClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:188) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:124) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1818) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer?
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.loadBalance(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:447) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:422) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:182) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

code of bufen sysadmin

```java
//Get user's infamation
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class SysUserController {

    @Autowired
    SysUserMapper sysUserMapper;

    /**
     * 返回用户信息
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/finUserById/{userId}")
    public SysUser finUserById(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        return sysUserMapper.findUserById(userId);
    }


}
```

I think pom.xml and other configurations are fine, so I omitted them.

Then there is the feign-api service：

```java
//Interface to obtain resources
@FeignClient(value = "sysadmin")
public interface SysAdminClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "finUserById/{userId}")
    SysUser finUserById(@PathVariable("userId") String userId);

    @GetMapping(value = "/findRolesByUserId/{userId}")
    List<SysRole> findRolesByUserId(@PathVariable("userId") String userId);

    @GetMapping(value="/findPermissionByUserId/{userId}")
    List<SysPermission> findPermissionByUserId(@PathVariable String userId);
}
```

Then there is the authentication service.I think there is a big problem here, because I really don’t know how to write. This is a simple case from the official website.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsServiceImpl myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    MyPasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // 配置表单登录，定义登录页面的相关参数和处理逻辑
        Customizer<FormLoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> formLoginConfigurerCustomizer = httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer -> {
            httpSecurityFormLoginConfigurer
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/userLogin")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password");
        };

        // 配置请求授权规则，任何请求都需要认证通过
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(formLoginConfigurerCustomizer);
        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return myPasswordEncoder;
    }


}
```

```java
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    SysAdminClient sysAdminClient;

    /**
     * 方法实现内容是： 根据用户名查询用户对象和用户的权限列表
     * @param userId 用户的登录账号
     * @return UserDetails接口类型对象
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException 用户名不存在异常
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("自定义登录服务 - loadUserByUsername方法执行");

        // 根据登录方式，查询用户
        SysUser sysUser = null;

        // 如果是用户名登录
        sysUser = sysAdminClient.finUserById(userId);

        //判断该账号是否存在
        if(sysUser == null) {
            System.out.println("用户：" + userId + "不存在");
            //用户不存在
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("用户名或密码错误");
        }

        //开始查询已登录的用户的权限集合
        String sysUserId = String.valueOf(sysUser.getId());
        //查询角色
        List<SysRole> roles = sysAdminClient.findRolesByUserId(sysUserId);
        System.out.println("roles:"+roles);
        //查询权限
        List<SysPermission> permissions = sysAdminClient.findPermissionByUserId(sysUserId);

        //定义一个字符串泛型的List集合
        List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SysRole role : roles){
            //角色名称纳入权限管理，必须增加前缀 ROLE_
            authorities.add("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName());
        }

        for(SysPermission permission : permissions){
            //权限字符串描述，不需要特定的任何前后缀
            authorities.add(permission.getPermit());
        }

        System.out.println("sysAccount:"+ sysUser);
        //返回UserDetails接口类型对象
        return new User(
                userId,//登录用户的账号
                sysUser.getPassword(),//登录密码，是服务端存储的密文
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities.toArray(new String[0]))//通过工具把字符串权限转换为Security定义的权限
        );

    }
}
```

I really don’t know what to do now, I have a headache from learning.